# How to get the key of a firebaseArray object

Tags: arrays, angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get the key for a returned firebaseArray record but am having no luck.

I have aservice that runs the following to return a store

```
getStore: function(uid, id){
    var ref = firebase.database().ref('u/'+uid+'/stores/'+id+'/i/');
     // to take an action after the data loads, use the $loaded() promise
     return $firebaseArray(ref);
}
```

I use the following to get eeach record by calling the service

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.storesList.length; i++){
    var storeInfo = Stores.getStore($rootScope.user['uid'], $scope.storesList[i]['$id']);
    storeInfo.$loaded().then(function(data){
            $scope.stores.push(data);
            console.log($scope.stores);
    });
}
```

In my html I can access various properties within the array

```
<li ng-repeat="store in stores">
      <span class="store-address">{{store.$getRecord('name').$value}}</span>
      <span class="store-address">{{store.$getRecord('address1').$value}}</span>
</li>
```

But I cannot seem to get the id for each store record from within the ng-repeat

Answer (score 1):

To get the id simply call the $id on the item.

```
<li ng-repeat="store in stores">
      <span class="store-address">{{store.$getRecord('name').$value}}</span>
      <span class="store-address">{{store.$getRecord('address1').$value}}</span>
      <span class="store-address">{{store.$id}}</span>
</li>
```

See: https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/reference.md#firebasearray

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getting yourself complicated, try this simple code!

```
var ref = new Firebase(url);
ref.once("value", function(list) {
    var subData    = list.val();
    var subDataKey = list.key();
    console.log(subDataKey);
```

This must help you!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by switch from firebaseArray to firebaseObject which contains an $id parameter